# Control de usuarios en java

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando una banca electrónica como proyecto final para la universidad, mi proyecto consta de los siguientes frames:

```
LogIn
Estado de cuenta
Info de cuenta
Registros
funciones
```

como dato adicional todos los campos están guardados en una base de datos `mysql`, en donde funciones te muestra estado de cuenta e info de cuenta, estado de cuenta deberia tu numero de tarjeta y el saldo disponible e info de cuenta te muestra los datos relacionados con tu cuenta, tales como nombre, apellido, ciudad, etc., hasta ahora ya tengo configurado el frame de login pues compara los datos dentro de la base de datos para acceder al frame de funciones en donde te permite acceder a los antes mencionados frames.

Mi problema viene en que no encuentro la manera para que se muestren los datos necesarios dependiendo de la sesión con la que se inicie, por ejemplo el usuario 12 tiene $100 en su cuenta, esta información es la que se debe mostrar en el frame de estado de cuenta. Conozco la consulta para `mysql` ya que tengo creada la base de datos con 3 tablas relacionadas entre si para poder mostrar la información, lo que no se es como tener el control de los usuarios.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código para poder tener una mejor idea de cómo intentas mostrar los datos?

Comment: Comentas que tienes un apartado `LogIn`. Por lo que tendrás una tabla en la base de datos con los usuarios y sus credenciales. No te sirve eso para filtrar los resultados?

Comment: Tu aplicación: ¿Es un servidor?  ¿Es una aplicación de escritorio "monousuario"?

Comment: tengo una tabla en la base de datos donde se guarda usuario y contraseña, lo que sucede es que desconozco de que manera mostrarlo en java, es decir conozco la logica de lo que se tiene que hacer sin embargo al momento de mostrarlo en java es cuando me pierdo

Comment: es una aplicacion de escritorio

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que para que haya una sessión tiene que haber usuarios con una estructura de servidor que te permita crear la sessión y mantenerla en memoria, en una app de escritorio lo que estarías haciendo es simular esa acción, no es imposible, no me parece práctico pero bueno, estarías creando roles o algo parecido, si querés lo que te ofrezco es pasarte un mini proyecto de cómo se tendría que hacer con servlets y una orientación al final de cómo la deberías hacer si al final querés usar swing. Pero respondeme por sí o por no asi no pierdo tiempo.

Comment: me parece muy bien, te agradeceria mucho por tu proyecto

Comment: como dato adicional aclaro que en efecto es una simulacion de sesiones ya que lo estaria ejecutando solo de manera local

Comment: calculale dos horas

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la respuesta no es exactamente la que esperás te paso un mini ejemplo de sessions en servlets y al final cómo podrías aplicarlo a Swing.

Aunque los pasos son más complejos guardá esta pregunta para más adelante que seguramente vas a ver servlet en su momento, sin embargo como te digo hay formas de emular comportamientos a swing y al final voy a tratar de emular esto mismo  swing en forma más simple y proponiendo ideas.

## Como funcionaría Servlets

**Primero que Nada en el paquete que tiene las entidades declaramos por ejemplo la Clase Cliente:**

Como verás tiene un contructor vacío y otro con atributos, el vacío lo tenemos por si queremos crear un objeto cliente y sólo setear algún dato en específico como va a pasar un poco más adelante.

```
    package com.soa.entities;

    public class Client {

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private double savings;

        public Client() {

        }

        public Client(int id, String name, double savings) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.savings = savings;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public double getSavings() {
            return savings;
        }

        public void setSavings(double savings) {
            this.savings = savings;
        }

    }
```

**Luego creamos una clase de conexión a la DB, ya que voy a mostrarte cómo poder rescatar el mismo dato de una página a la otra por una veriable de Session y también por datos persistidos en una DB. Dos cosas muy distintas, sin embargo la ultima es la que más se asemeja a lo que querés hacer en swing**

```
    package com.soa.dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class ConnectionStackOverflow {

        private final static String user = "root";
        private final static String password = "";

        public static Connection getConexion() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homebanking" , user, password);
            return connection;
        }

        public static void closeConnection() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
            getConexion().close();
        }
    }
```

Una vez hecha la conexión, tendrías que crear una DB en mysql llamada homebanking y una tabla con cuatro columnas:

id: int A_I, name: Varchar 20, lastname Varchar 20, savings: Double;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**A continuación creamos una clase controladora de lo que hacemos con el cliente y la DB.**

Entiendo que esto seguro va a ser chino básico al principio pero hay que verlo con paciencia y deglosarlo un poco.

```
    package com.soa.controllers;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import com.soa.dao.ConnectionStackOverflow;
    import com.soa.entities.Client;

    public class AccountController {

        /* Método para insertar un cliente a la DB */
        public static void insertClient(String name, String lastname, double savings) {
            Connection connection = null;
            /* Intentamos conectarnos */
            try {
                connection = ConnectionStackOverflow.getConexion();

                /* Si no es nula que entre al método que nos facilita realizar la insercción */
                if (connection != null) {
                    PreparedStatement ps;
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO accounts(name, lastname, savings) VALUES(?,?,?)";
                    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setString(1, name);
                    ps.setString(2, lastname);
                    ps.setDouble(3, savings);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.close();
                    System.out.println("Query executed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection appears to be null");
                }
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Cannot even connect");
                error.getMessage();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /*
         * Método para retornar un cliente por su id , este es que seguramente se usaría
         * en una app de Escritorio, llegando el id por un campo hidden
         */
        public static Client retriveClient(int id) {
            Connection connection = null;

            String name = null;
            double savings = 0;
            Client client = null;

            try {
                connection = ConnectionStackOverflow.getConexion();

                if (connection != null) {
                    Statement st;
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id=" + id;
                    st = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                    /*
                     * Mientras haya un resultado en la tabla le decimos que nos lo traiga y que a
                     * su vez grabe las variables recuperadas en name y savings, y por último lo
                     * agregamos a un cliente nuevo
                     */
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        name = rs.getString("name");
                        savings = rs.getDouble("savings");
                        client = new Client(id, name, savings);
                    }
                    /* Lo probamos por consola para ver si funcionó */
                    System.out.println(client.getSavings());
                    System.out.println("Query executed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection appears to be null");
                }
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Cannot even connect");
                error.getMessage();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            return client;
        }

        /*
         * Esta consulta no es recomendada ya que lo ideal es realizar la consulta sobre
         * el id y en este caso lo estoy haciendo sobre el name y lastname, va a ser
         * untema tuyo como solucionarlo
         */
        public static double getPersistedSavings(String name, String lastname) {
            Connection connection = null;
            double savings = 0;
            Client client = null;
            try {
                connection = ConnectionStackOverflow.getConexion();
                /*  Si la conexión no es nula entonces que pase al métodos de averiguación de datos */
                if (connection != null) {
                    Statement st;
                    String sql = "SELECT savings FROM accounts WHERE name='" + name + "' AND lastname='" + lastname + "' ";
                    st = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                    /*  Sólo queremos los savings o saldo, usamos el constructor vacío y le seteamos el valor recuperado    */
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        savings = rs.getDouble("savings");
                        client = new Client();
                        client.setSavings(savings);
                    }
                    System.out.println(client.getSavings());
                    System.out.println("Query executed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection appears to be null");
                }
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Cannot even connect");
                error.getMessage();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
            return savings;
        }

    }
```

**Servlets en gral van en otro paquete y se tienen que declarar sí o sí en el archivo WEB-INF/web.xml más adelante lo pongo también. Vamos a tener dos, uno para insertar Clientes a la DB y creando sessiones y otro para recuperar de la DB como también haciendo un pasamanos de datos entre session.**

```
    package com.soa.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import com.soa.controllers.AccountController;

    public class InsertClientServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            try {

                /* Recuperamos los datos de los inputs del jsp */
                String name = request.getParameter("name");
                String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
                String savings = request.getParameter("savings");

                /* Parseamos el String y lo pasamos a double */
                double doubleSavings = Double.parseDouble(savings);

                /* LLamamos al método que inserta los datos a la DB */
                AccountController.insertClient(name, lastname, doubleSavings);

                /*
                 * Además de haberlo insertado creamos una session y le agremos los siguientes
                 * atributos, name, lastname, savings
                 */
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                session.setAttribute("name", name);
                session.setAttribute("lastname", lastname);
                session.setAttribute("savings", doubleSavings);

                /*
                 * Cuando todo termina que nos derive a otra web donde vamos a consultar los
                 * savings por datos persistidos y por pasamanos de sessiones
                 */
                getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/querySavings.jsp").forward(request, response);

            } catch (Exception error) {
                error.getMessage();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

**El archivo index.jsp donde va aestar el formulario de ingreso de cliente a la DB**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function send() {
            var frm = document.frmInsertClient;
            frm.submit();
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <h1>Insertar Cliente</h1>

        <form action="InsertClientServlet" method="get" name="frmInsertClient">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nombre: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td><label>Apellido: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Saldo: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="savings" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" value="boton" onclick="send()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**El segundo Servlet que donde vamos a procesar los datos que recibimos del primero**

```
    package com.soa.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import com.soa.controllers.AccountController;

    public class QuerySavingsServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            try {
                /* Grabados en session */
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                pw.println("Este saldo es que escribimos en la pantallas pasadas y que lo grabamos en memoria Session");
                pw.println("******************************   " + session.getAttribute("savings")
                        + "   **************************************");

                /* Consultados en la Base de Datos, información persistida */
                String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
                String lastname = (String) session.getAttribute("lastname");
                double persistedSavings = AccountController.getPersistedSavings(name, lastname);
                pw.println("Este saldo es el que está persistido en la DB y que consultamos por medio una consulta");
                pw.println("******************************   " + persistedSavings
                        + "   **************************************");

            } catch (Exception error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

        }

    }
```

**El archivo querySavings.jsp donde vamos a tener un form que se conecta al servlet anterior y realiza una consulta a la DB y asu vez también te devuelve el valor gravado en session.**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="com.soa.entities.Client"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Averiguar saldo</title>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function send() {
            var frm = document.frmSavings;
            frm.submit();
        }
    </script>
    <body>

        <h1>Averiguar saldo</h1>

        <%
            session.getAttribute("name");
            session.getAttribute("savings");
            session.getAttribute("lastname");
        %>
    Esta es la sessión de <% out.print(session.getAttribute("name")); %><br>

        <form action="QuerySavingsServlet" method="get" name="frmSavings">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<% out.print(session.getAttribute("name")); %> /> <br> 
            <input type="text" value=<% out.print(session.getAttribute("savings")); %>> <input type="button" value="Averiguar Saldo" onclick="send()" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Archivo de configuración web.xml donde van declarado los dos servlets.**

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <display-name>StackOverflowWeb</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>InsertClientServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.soa.servlets.InsertClientServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>InsertClientServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/InsertClientServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>QuerySavingsServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.soa.servlets.QuerySavingsServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>QuerySavingsServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/QuerySavingsServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**Este es el resultado final, dos datos, uno de session en memoria y otra persistida, vamos a tomar la forma en la que recuperamos la persistida para Swing.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Como hacer algo similar en Swing

Creamos una primer pantalla, la cual pueden hacerse varias cosas, como por ejemplo reutilizar el código que usamos para insertar en la DB pero usando los TextField, o sino cargar directamente a manopla la DB y usar esa pantalla para recuperar los datos.

Para que toda insercción funcione bien hay que seguir algunas pautas y usar algunas clases o interfaces como PreparedStatement o Statement y el Resultset para la devolución de datos. Arriba hice una insercción y dos recuperos de datos con sus métodos.

```
        package com.soa.view;

        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;

        import com.soa.controllers.ClientController;

        public class LoginFrame implements ActionListener {

            /*
             * Hacemos un primer ventana donde el primer input es el nombre, el segundo es
             * apellido y el tercero es id en disabled
             */
            public JFrame jframe;
            public JPanel jpanel;
            public JTextField text1, text2, text3;
            public JButton jbutton;

            public LoginFrame() {

                jframe = new JFrame();
                jpanel = new JPanel();

                text1 = new JTextField(20);
                text2 = new JTextField(20);
                text3 = new JTextField(3);
                text3.disable();

                jbutton = new JButton("Consultar");

                jframe.add(jpanel);
                jpanel.add(text1, "Nombre");
                jpanel.add(text2, "Saldo");
                jpanel.add(text3, "id");
                jpanel.add(jbutton);

                jframe.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
                jframe.setVisible(true);

                /*
                 * creas un action listener para que a su vez rescate información persistida en
                 * la DB
                 */
                this.jbutton.addActionListener(this);

            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent obj) {
                if (obj.equals(jbutton)) {

                    /* Esta clase no existe en mi proyecto pero la estoy proponiendo junto con el métodode insercción   */
                    ClientController.insertClientToDB(text1, text2);
                    /* Los datos se van a insertar si está bien hecho el método y la tabla  */

                    /*Creamos otra ventana pero esta vez de consulta */
                    QueryJframe qf = new QueryJFrame();

                    /* y cerramos la anterior */
                    jframe.dispose();
                }

            }

        }
```

**Ahora pasamos a Crear el otro Frame que le vamos a poner QueryFrame, en el mismo vamos a recuperar los datos con un Statement y ResultSet, activado por un boton y la interfaz ActionListener.**

Repito que este proyecto swing no lo tengo hecho en mi Eclipse, lo estoy haciendo sobre la marcha y proponiendo ideas, por ende si copian y pegan algun que otro error y/o advertencia puede que les aparezca.

```
        package com.soa.view;

        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JLabel;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;

        import com.soa.controllers.ClientController;

        public class QueryJframe implements ActionListener{


            /*
             * Hacemos un primer ventana donde el primer input es el nombre, el segundo es
             * apellido, vamos autilizar los mismos para recuperar el dato savings de la DB
             */
            public JFrame jframe;
            public JPanel jpanel;
            public JTextField text1, text2;
            public JButton jbutton;
            public JLabel jlabel;

            public QueryJframe() {

                jframe = new JFrame();
                jpanel = new JPanel();

                text1 = new JTextField(20);
                text2 = new JTextField(20);
                jlabel = new JLabel("Acá va a estar el reultado");


                jbutton = new JButton("Savings");

                jframe.add(jpanel);
                jpanel.add(text1, "Nombre");
                jpanel.add(text2, "Saldo");
                jpanel.add(jbutton);


                jframe.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 250);
                jframe.setVisible(true);

                /*
                 * creas un action listener para que a su vez rescate información persistida en
                 * la DB
                 */
                this.jbutton.addActionListener(this);

            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent obj) {
                if (obj.equals(jbutton)) {
                    /* Se la asinamos a una nueva variable double que tomará el valor que hay en la DB */
                    /* Esta clase no existe en mi proyecto pero la estoy proponiendo junto con el métodode insercción, este mismo deberìa ser un método que devuelva un double  */
                    double savings = ClientController.getClientSavings(text1, text2);

                    /* setText() solo acepta Strings por ende tenemos que pasar de double a String */
                    String strSavings = Double.toString(savings);

                    jlabel.setText(strSavings);
                }

            }

        }
```

En conclusión a todo esto es que podemos hacer que atraves de los campos de JText podemos ingresar datos y que otro método traiga de la DB, o sino algú campo hidden que no recuerdo si hay, si no hay ponemos un JTextField y le aplicamos un disabled(), que tome el valor del id que queremos consultar el saldo y creamos la query correspondiente. Es más simple por Swing pero a su vez parece que es menos completo, sin embargo por servlets es demasiado complejo con muchas ideas y vueltas, repito que mi intención es que se pueda ver estructuralmente los dos casos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo establecería un campo de tipo "permiso" o "credenciales" para que, en función del tipo de usuario, se mostrara los campos que tu deseas en función de la cuenta. En mi caso por ejemplo, hice una aplicación de control de un colegio.

Las cuentas tipo "admin" accedían a todo, las de tipo "profesor" no podían registrar otros profesores pero sí alumnos, y las cuentas tipo "alumno" sólo podían ver resultados. Eso controlado por un campo "credencial" con valores 0, 1 ó 2. Cada campo es un tipo de cuenta.

No sé si te he ayudado y espero haber entendido tu duda.

Edito: Es evidente, pero en la pantalla de LogIn tienes que abrir la conexión a la base de datos y lanzar los datos de acceso contra ella, con un nombre de usuario que se almacena en la tabla de usuario y el campo de tipo de cuenta.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta sin embargo lo que me mantiene en la duda es de que forma puedo devolver los datos en java, la forma de realizar el codigo

Comment: En plan esquema: Recoge los datos, construye el objeto persona, plásmalo por pantalla. En principio ese objeto tendrá los datos que sí quieres plasmar, si no me equivoco. Edito: ¿Usas algún ORM como Hibernate para trabajar entre los objetos y la base de datos?

Comment: Lo que estaba a punto de hacer es llamar a los datos en el frame de funciones para que de esa forma los envie ya sea a info de cliente o estado de cuenta.perdona pero es la primera vez que veo los terminos de hibernate y ORM

Comment: Vale, te lo explico en plan rápido. Hibernate lo usas en los objetos java que se convierten en datos de una tabla de SQL. De primeras el objeto persona, sus datos, se registran en la tabla persona a través de una sentencia de SQL por la que pasas los datos. Hibernate lo pones en el código del Objeto Java y mapeas sus atributos, para no pasar los datos del Objeto, sino que pasas el objeto como tal e Hibernate lo "traduce" y lo mete a la base de datos, ahorrando toda la parte de sentencias. Gracias a esto envías objetos y recibes objetos.

Comment: public void mostrar(String nick){
        nick = "123456";
        
        String sql= "select saldo from info where numtar='"+nick+"'";
        try {    
            stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
                this.jmonto.setText(sql);
            }else{
                
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

Estoy usando ese metodo para mostrar datos pero no muestra nada

Comment: Mira este proyecto con Login y BBDD MySQL. https://bitbucket.org/dosz/accesoadatos_ra3/src/abfd12dcc898fa72b08fb71b4cc39b36cc107634/Proyecto/?at=master